# Using an iPad, is it possible to install an APK on an Android device?

Tags: ios, apk

We're developing an Oculus Quest 2 app and one of our employees is going abroad for Christmas. Since we're going to keep updating the app, he wants to be able to install the new versions on his headset so he can test it, but he only has an iPad pro. He doesn't want to take anything other than his iPad pro if possible.

So I am looking for a way to install an APK file on an Android device from an iPad pro.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just upload the APK into any cloud(Google drive, dropbox) and download it from an Android device.
There is no standard way to install Android app from iOS.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I ended up sideloading an APK Installer app inside the quest 2, in order to install other APK directly from the headset.